# How to find all and replace all on blogspot html editor?

Tags: blogger

on blogspot html editor code I search for specific code using ctrl+F shortcut, but I want to replace all the results with other code

How to do that, please?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about the Blogspot HTML editor, but if I may be so bold, maybe you are using the wrong tool for the job. If I may be so bold as to recommend something, take a look at Notepad++, which has powerful support for Searching, Replacing, Syntax highlighting etc. It's only for Windows though.

Comment: @Refugnic Eternium thanks so much. it is a good solution. I may use any code editor

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Let me just change that into an answer, so you can close the question properly.

Comment: yes, I will mark it as the answer for my question. jut make it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is basically just text.
As such, you can use any 'text editor' you want and just copy the source code into the HTML editor once you are done.

A good tool I'm using on Windows is Notepad++, which has support for syntax highlighting, auto completion features and, to get back to your question, it supports searching/replacing with a variety of options, including by using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut  `CTRL + SHIFT + F`  to  find and replace on Blogger Editor